# When I click a method in eclipse with Command (ctrl) it opens xcode

Tags: xcode, eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

In eclipse for mac when you press command and then click on a method or variable it will take you to were it is located. HOWEVER suddenly instead of doing that it started opening XCODE, because it was treating every click as opening the .java file. 
I thought that maybe it was key bindings so I went into eclipse and reset all key bindings, so now it jumps to the correct part of the eclipse document... then it opens XCODE.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your *.java files in eclipse "open with" eclipse not XCODE.

Comment: Its actually "open with default editor", but you led me to the right place! Thanks!